# Update MySQL Column Timestamp

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

I have this query:

```
 SELECT `ListingDeadline` FROM `listings` WHERE `listing_type_sid` = 6 AND `active` = 1;
```

Running this give me a result of 183 results of the column `ListingDeadline` in the following format:

```
2014-03-28 00:00:00
2014-03-30 00:00:00
```

This column is a DateTime type column where users select a date for a listing deadline and it returns the date and appends a time stamp. By default this timestamp was 00:00:00 which I've just changed to 23:59:59. What I want to do is update the current listingDeadline timestamp results with this new value (23:59:59) so that the 00:00:00 is replaced by 23:59:59 for all the 183 results.

Any one with an idea of what query that I can add to the one above to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from some peeps finally got it to work using the following query. Hope it helps anyone else out there who may have a similar issue.

```
UPDATE `listings`
SET `listings`.`ListingDeadline`= ADDDATE(`listings`.`ListingDeadline`, INTERVAL -1 SECOND)
WHERE `listings`.`listing_type_sid` = 6
AND `listings`.`active` = 1;
```

Thanks for all your tips and ideas, helped alot.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
Update `listings` SET `ListingDeadline` = '23:59:59' 
WHERE  `listing_type_sid` = 6 AND `active` = 1
AND    `ListingDeadline` = '00:00:00'
```

Comment: Won't this remove the date values? I want to only change the 00:00:00 with 23:59:59 and keep the dates.

Comment: I tested this too and it doesn't seem to work. Any more ideas?

Comment: more idea is when you share your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your question can also be interpreted as just altering the query result.
If so, try this. It can also be used in an update.

```
SELECT `ListingDeadline` - INTERVAL 1 SECOND AS ListingDeadLine FROM `listings` WHERE `listing_type_sid` = 6 AND `active` = 1;
```

Comment: Not just altering the query result but also updating it. Works well when all I want to do is alter the result.

Comment: Using a Insert results in a mySQL error. ....for the right synyax to use near '-INTERVAL 1 SECOND AS ListingDeadline FROM `listings` WHERE `listing_type_sid` = 6 AND " at line 1

Comment: What does your insert look like? The part the error cites doesn't look like an insert.

Comment: Exactly the same as your query above, except I replaced "Select" with "Insert". Got it to work though.